# PHP - IP address Nameserver lookup.

Tags: php

I am trying to find a function that can query the name servers of an IP address. I have found lots of documentation on how to obtain the rDNS(PTR) of the IP address but nothing with the name servers. Does this function exist?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Will gethostbyaddr not work for you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Comment: Are you asking how to identify which nameserver is authoritative for a given host name?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Comment: The gethostbyaddr worked perfectly. Thank you for all the replies.